# Incremental Date Update for Groups

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have data in this format:

```
ID| DATE
--------
1 | 02/23/2014
1 | 05/15/2011
1 | 01/05/2017
2 | 12/21/2013
3 | 10/10/2016
3 | 09/05/2015
```

For Each ID Group I want to update the dates starting from yesterday onward(decreasing order).
Considering todays date is 09/28/2017, Output should be like:

```
ID | DATE
--------
1 | 09/27/2017
1 | 09/26/2017
1 | 09/25/2017
2 | 09/27/2017
3 | 09/27/2016
3 | 09/26/2017
```

My approach was (which is not working)

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET DATE = CURRENT DATE - p.a days
FROM (
    SELECT DATE
        ,ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC
            ) a
    FROM TABLE
    ) p
WHERE DATE = p.DATE
    AND ID = p.ID
WITH ur;
```

Kindly suggest any method to achieve the same.

Edit:

Database : DB2

Error :

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N An unexpected token "from"      was found following "rent date - p.a days". Expected tokens may include: "".

`Date` Column Data type: Date

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query attempt is product specific.)

Comment: Column date's data type?

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: Ordering by the column under partition will have no effect on the results.  I'd not be surprised if the optimizer drops the clause.  Did you mean `'DATE'`?  If those are the only two columns you have, though, the ordering is irrelevant (since the data is overwritten).

Comment: have you solved? have you found any answer useful?

Comment: no, I couldn't find any solution. Although this requirement is not relevant as of now; I would like to know the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT ID,  
    DATEADD(DAY
         , -1 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)), @Today) [DATE] 
FROM MyTable
```

For Update

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()

;WITH T AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        [DATE],  
        DATEADD(DAY,-1 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)), @Today) [NEW_DATE] 
    FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE M 
    SET [DATE] = T.[NEW_DATE]
FROM 
    MyTable M INNER JOIN T ON  M.ID = T.ID AND M.[DATE] = T.[DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

for db2:

```
update t 
    set DATE = NewDate
from TABLE t
join (
    select T.DATE, T.ID, (CURRENT DATE - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY T.ID ASC)) NewDate
    FROM TABLE T
) p  on t.DATE = p.DATE and t.ID = p.ID
```

for sql-server:

```
update t 
    set DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -p.a, GETDATE())
from TABLE t
join (
    select T.DATE, T.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY T.ID ASC) a
    FROM TABLE T
) p  on t.DATE = p.DATE and t.ID = p.ID
```

Comment: DATEADD function is not working in DB2. When I replaced the DATEADD with 'current date - p.a days' I am getting same error as mentioned in OP

Comment: try with this, I think the problem could be in the missing join in your update or the unrecognized `p.a` notation. I have changed it to `NewDate`